# How much does "X damage up" affect damage?

Tags: triangle-strategy

Triangle Strategy has some character upgrades in the format "*X* damage up", such as "Fire Damage Up" and "Ice Damage Up" on Narve. However, the in-game UI doesn't clarify how *much* damage is increased. Is it a flat value? A percentage? I've looked at some guides but they don't seem to have the actual numbers either.